# when build oozie4.3 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo1.maven.org: Name or service not known

Tags: maven, hadoop, oozie

I have Built the environment Hadoop 2.6.5 Cluster in the virtual machine.

The host(Physical machine) cannot access the network. then I change
Virtual machines use agents to access the Internet by

```
[hadoop@master bin]$ less ~/.bashrc 
export http_proxy="128.24.34.143:808"
```

so,the virtual machies can access the internet just as baidu.com below:

```
[hadoop@master tmp]$ wget baidu.com
```

> 2017-09-02 19:26:28--  http://baidu.com/
>   Connecting to 145.24.34.143:808... connected.
>   Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>   Length: 81 [text/html]
>   Saving to: 鈥渋ndex.html.4鈥?
>
> 100%[======>] 81          --.-K/s   in 0s
>
> 2017-09-02 19:26:28 (9.05 MB/s) - 鈥渋ndex.html.4鈥?saved [81/81]
>
> [hadoop@master tmp]$

But

```
[hadoop@master sbin]$ cd /nfs_share/hadoop_soft/oozie-4.3.0/bin/
[hadoop@master bin]$ ./mkdistro.sh -X -Phadoop-2 -Dhadoop.auth.version=2.6.5 -Ddistcp.version=2.6.5 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.5 -Dpig.version=0.16.0 -Dhive.version=2.1.1 -Dhbase.version=1.2.6  -Dsqoop.version=1.4.6 -DskipTests
```

the error below:

> Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:17 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): repo1.maven.org: Name or service not known and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 21, column 13
>   that is why ???
>   if anyone meet it ?? thanks

Comment: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo1.maven.org: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1295)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1248)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1164)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)

Comment: i have solve by cd /usr/share/apache-maven/conf